# ios7 - Why is the UITextView centered vertically when I start typing

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitextview, autolayout

I set the autolayout to greater than or equal than 75. I seems to be okay when the it loads, but when I start typing on the uitextview, it shrinks in height (1 line) and is centered vertically. Note that I have a vertical space constraint from the label to the uitextview (box) .

Picture 1:
[image: It looks fine here]

Picture 2:
[image: It shrinks]

Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove that constraint and set the contraints to the fixed height you want. Guessing it is somewhere around 100pts